# How to get a static builder method from protobuf built java class?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have multiple protobuf generated java classes for different protobuf schemas. In my actual project I import all those classes and based on the json, **I need to select one of those class objects whose builder method I will use**.
My approach is to create a map <string, Message.message> and based on the key, I select the corresponding builder class.

Issue is, newBuilderForType() is non static and everything else is static. Is there any way to get a static builder from the proto created java file?

Code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Collections;
import com.google.protobuf.Message;
import com.netapp.asup.proto.ProtoOne.protoOne;
import com.netapp.asup.proto.ProtoTwo.protoTwo;
import com.netapp.asup.proto.ProtoThree.protoThree;
import com.netapp.asup.proto.ProtoFour.protoFour;

public class SchemaEntityMap {
    private static Map<String, Message.Builder> SchemaMap = new HashMap<String, Message.Builder>();

    static {
        Map<String, Message.Builder> map = new HashMap<String, Message.Builder>();
        map.put("proto one", protoOne.newBuilderForType());
        map.put("proto one", protoTwo.newBuilderForType());
        map.put("proto one", protoThree.newBuilderForType());
        map.put("proto one", protoFour.newBuilderForType());
        SchemaMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    public static Message.Builder getEntityBuilder(String entityName) {
        return SchemaMap.get(entityName);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for newBuilder()?